# How to get the Name attribute of an anchor tag

Tags: jquery

Here is my html markup (cut down)

```
<li class="tab"><a href="#" name="content1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href="#" name="content2">Tab 1</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href="#" name="content3">Tab 1</a></li>
```

All I want to do is get the `name` attribute of the `<a>` tag when its parent `<li>` is clicked, as such:

```
$('li.tab').bind('click', function (e) {
    var contentRequested = $(this + " a").name; // <-- this is not working to get the Name attribute
    alert(contentRequested)
    e.preventDefault;
});
```

How do I use `$(this)` and then find the `<a>` tag within it and finally get the `name` attribute value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like `$(this).find('a').attr('name');` would work:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7F6vH/)

```
$('li.tab').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('a').attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  var contentRequested = $(this + " a").name;
```

change to

```
  var contentRequested = $(this).find("a").attr("name");
```